# RadGrid not displaying rows in sequence (Insert record sequence)

Tags: asp.net, radgrid

Below is the HTML code of RadGrid:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RGGSTAcCode" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  
                                                                                         ShowFooter="True" GroupingEnabled="False" ShowStatusBar="true"         
                                                                                         AllowAutomaticInserts="False" AllowAutomaticUpdates="False" AllowAutomaticDeletes="true"
                                                                                         OnNeedDataSource= "rggstAcCode_NeedDataSource" OnItemDataBound="rggstAcCode_ItemDataBound"                    
                                                                                         OnInsertCommand="rggstAcCode_InsertCommand" OnDeleteCommand="rggstAcCode_DeleteCommand"
                                                                                         OnUpdateCommand="rggstAcCode_UpdateCommand" OnItemCommand="RGGSTAcCode_ItemCommand"
                                                                                         EnableEmbeddedSkins="true" Skin="Outlook">

                                                                                        <mastertableview commanditemdisplay="Top" autogeneratecolumns="false" datakeynames="AccountCodeID" 
                                                                                            insertitempageindexaction="ShowItemOnCurrentPage" ShowFooter="True" ShowHeadersWhenNoRecords="true">
                                    <CommandItemSettings AddNewRecordText="New" />
                                    <Columns>
                                        <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName="imagebutton1" ButtonType="ImageButton"></telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>

                                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="in_line" HeaderText="Line Number"> 
                                          <ItemTemplate> 
                                             <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%# Container.DataSetIndex+1 %>"></asp:Label> 
                                          </ItemTemplate> 
                                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="AccountCode" HeaderText="Account Code">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode") + " - " + Eval("AccountDescription")%>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>

                                                <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlAccountCode" runat="server" Height="200" Width="250" DropDownWidth="350" 
                                                    HighlightTemplatedItems="true" Filter="Contains" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="AccountDescription" DataValueField="AccountCodeID"
                                                    OnItemsRequested="ddlAccountCode_ItemsRequested" ItemsPerRequest="50" EnableItemCaching="true"
                                                    AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlAccountCode_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                                    EnableLoadOnDemand="True" ShowMoreResultsBox="true" EnableVirtualScrolling="true">
                                                </telerik:RadComboBox>

                                            </EditItemTemplate>
                                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="AccountDescription" HeaderText="Description"
                                            UniqueName="AccountDescription" SortExpression="AccountDescription" ReadOnly="True">                                           
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>                                     

                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn aggregate="SUM" DataFormatString="{0:n}" DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" FooterAggregateFormatString="Total : {0:###,##0.00}" 
                                            UniqueName="Amount" SortExpression="Amount" FooterStyle-BackColor="#ffc04c">
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" /> 
                                            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" /> 
                                            <ColumnValidationSettings EnableRequiredFieldValidation="true">
                                                <RequiredFieldValidator ForeColor="Red" Text="*This field is required">
                                                </RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            </ColumnValidationSettings>                                            
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Remark" HeaderText="IFCA Description"
                                            UniqueName="Remark" SortExpression="Remark">
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" /> 
                                            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />                                             
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>                                        

                                        <telerik:GridButtonColumn ConfirmTextFormatString="Are you sure you want to Delete Selected Account Code(s)?" ConfirmTextFields="AccountCodeID"
                                         ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" UniqueName="DeleteColumn" ButtonType="ImageButton"></telerik:GridButtonColumn>
                                    </Columns>

                                    <EditFormSettings>
                                        <EditColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" />
                                    </EditFormSettings>
                                    <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="True" PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox" />
                                </mastertableview>
                                                                                    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Stored Procedure to display data in RadGrid:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Invoice].[usp_tbl_AccountCode_Select_Transaction]
    @RequestID nvarchar(50)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Select
        AccountCodeID,
        RequestID,
        AccountCode,
        AccountDescription,
        Amount,
        Remark
    From [Invoice].[tbl_AccountCodeTransaction] (NOLOCK)
    Where RequestID = @RequestID
```

What I observed here is, If user enters following rows with following amount:

**1)** 0.00 (when 1st time insert, this will come as 1st row)
**2)** 2,000.00 (when 2nd time insert, this will come as 2nd row)
**3)** 6,767.00 (when 3rd time insert, this will come as 1st row (in place of becoming 3rd row)
and previous 1st row will become 2nd row & previous 2nd row will become
as 3rd row)
**4)** 56,565.00 (when 4th time insert, this will come as 3rd row (in place of becoming 4th row)
& 2,000.00 will become as 4th row, & 0.00 will become as 2nd row, & 
6,767.00 will remain as 1st row.

Below is the snapshot of above defined issue:
[image]

I want that the data should display in sequence, when I insert the
rows in RadGrid. i.e., whatever I insert 1st should display first,
2nd as 2nd , 3rd as 3rd and so on. not in random order.

I tried to put the "Auto generate Line numbers" but with that also
its not working as expected.

Please let me know why it is not displaying data in sequence ?

Please reply

Comment: You need to track in DB somehow the order of request (for example add there column DateCreated defaulted to GETDATE() to tbl_AccountCodeTransaction) - otherwise your problem is with SQL. SQL doesn't guarantee the order of row unless explicitly specified via ORDER BY clause in your stored procedure. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236352/default-row-order-in-select-query-sql-server-2008-vs-sql-2012

Comment: Please add orderby clause in your stored procedure.  Line number is only display row number in radgrid its not displayed the sequence detail.

Answer (score 0):

I had added `Order By CreatedDate` (this CreatedDate column saves both date and time) in `Select` statement and its working fine. Thank you so much for the help @Ondrej Svejdar and @Jayesh Goyani