# Get Last Five Record From Table

Tags: sql-server

I want Last Five Record from table. Condition is Column contains duplicate and null values.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student] (
    [Student_Name] [VARCHAR](50) NULL
)

INSERT INTO Student
VALUES
      ('Mukesh')
    , ('Vinod')
    , ('Mukesh')
    , (NULL)
    , ('Shree')
    , ('Raj')
    , (NULL)
    , ('Abhijit')
    , ('Raju')
    , ('Sharon')
    , ('Ashok')
    , ('Meena')
    , ('Mukesh')
    , (NULL)

SELECT * FROM Student
```

[image]

Note: I want Last Five Record From Above Table

Result like that:
[image]

Comment: How do you define the last records?

Comment: Without an explicit `ORDER BY` clause, the order of the result set will not be guaranteed. So unless you specify which column define the _last records_, the answers you'll be getting here will not be accurate.

Comment: last record is last row of entire table data

Comment: I suggest you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236352/default-row-order-in-select-query-sql-server-2008-vs-sql-2012).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why is the logic behind your desired result?

Comment: This can't be done. without a column that specifies the order of inserted values (like an identity column or a create date column) there is no possible way to guarantee the order of the select statement will be the same order the records was inserted to the database.

Comment: suppose i have 120 record in student table, now i want last 5 recently inserted record in student table. I don't have any student id or serial no column which can be describe order of data

Comment: Well then I guess you sool. Unless you can add a column to specify the order of inserts (like identity or create date) it simply can't be done.

Comment: You can try Devart's answer, but it will not return the same set of data everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Student TABLE (Student_Name VARCHAR(50)) 

INSERT INTO @Student
VALUES
      ('Mukesh'), ('Vinod'), ('Mukesh'), (NULL)
    , ('Shree'), ('Raj'), (NULL), ('Abhijit'), ('Raju')
    , ('Sharon'), ('Ashok'), ('Meena'), ('Mukesh'), (NULL)

SELECT TOP(5) Student_Name
FROM (
    SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1/0)
    FROM @Student
) t
ORDER BY rn DESC
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee to return the same result all the time.

Comment: i like this query, but why an extra Column is coming rn, i want only student_Name column

Comment: @Surendra you are welcome :) BTW please add a PK for your table

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @c int
set @c = (select COUNT(*) from Student)
select *
from
(select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by student_id) as row, *
from Student) t
where t.row between (@c-5) and @c
```

Try this one.

Update:

```
declare @c int
set @c = (select COUNT(*) from Student)
select *
from
(select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select 1)) as row, *
from Student) t
where t.row between (@c-5) and @c
```

Comment: Not Working. I don't have student_id Column in student table

Answer (score -4):

Use DISTINCT to remove duplicates from the result set.
example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT expressions
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions];
```

and use LIMIT to limit the result count

Comment: `LIMIT` is **not** a valid keword/operation in **Microsoft SQL Server** or standard ANSI / ISO SQL -