# SQL output order

Tags: sql

would you say it is safe to assume that output returned by

```
   select * from table1;
```

will be ordered in the same way as the output of:

```
select * from table1 where table1.a<0;
```

where a is some random attribute of table1?

thanks!

Comment: I don't see why not

Comment: It may depend on your DBMS software (SQL Server, MySQL, etc) - but generally no order is guaranteed.

Comment: No order is guaranteed unless it's explicitly specified, but it definitely depends on the DBMS

Comment: This post might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236352/default-row-order-in-select-query-sql-server-2008-vs-sql-2012

Comment: The general consensus is to never rely on the inherit ordering of your DB's storage. It will only end in tears. Use an `ORDER BY` clause in your SQL if it's important.

Comment: Do you mean order of the rows or order of the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean columns then I have never seen it different from the order when edit table in SSMS but I am not sure if that is a hard rule.

There is no inherent order to rows.  In absence of a sort the exact same query is not guaranteed to return rows in the same order each time.

this will be the same

```
select * from table1 
order by table1.PK;

select * from table1 where table1.a<0
order by table1.PK;
```

even a table with a clustered PK is not guaranteed to return rows in that order without an order by clause

This has to be a dup.   I will look for one and delete.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the column is defined in database schema so you should consider the returned sequence of column in `select *` alway the same (for changing the column sequence there are specific command that alter this value in schema, is a variant of alter table)

the order of the row no .. if you want to be sure of a specific order by result for the selected rows  you must explicitally set using a order by clause

```
 select * from your_table
 order by your_column
```