# Why items repeat in Prisma pagination with orderBy?

Tags: mysql, orm, pagination, prisma, prisma2

The data looks as follows:

13 users with id's 2-13. User 2 got 2 likes, user 10 got 2 likes, user 3 got 1 like. The rest didn't get any likes.

Prisma query looks like this:

```
return this.prisma.user.findMany({
  skip: Number(page) * Number(size),
  take: Number(size),
  orderBy: { likesReceived: { _count: "desc" } 
});
```

When I send a query to the database, ordering by likesReceived I get these responses:

| page | size | items id's |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | 2, 10, 3, 4, **14** |
| 1 | 5 | 6, 7, 8, 9, 11 |
| 2 | 5 | 12, 13, **14** |

User 14 appears twice, and user 5 is missing. Why?

Additional sorting by id fixes the problem:

```
return this.prisma.user.findMany({
  skip: Number(page) * Number(size),
  take: Number(size),
  orderBy: [{ likesReceived: { _count: "desc" } }, { id: "asc" }],
});
```

Results:

| page | size | items id's |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | 2, 10, 3, 4, 5 |
| 1 | 5 | 6, 7, 8, 9, 11 |
| 2 | 5 | 12, 13, 14 |

When is specifying a second parameter in orderBy with pagination necessary for it to work well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with `Laravel` using `sqlserver`.

`Laravel` was doing a different query for the first page than the subsequent pages. For page 1 they used...

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM users
```

while for subsequent pages they used `row_number()`, something like...

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() row_num, 
        *
    FROM
        users
    ) u    
WHERE
    row_num > 100 AND row_num <=201;
```

`Sqlserver` doesn't do a default `order by` [Default row order in SELECT query - SQL Server 2008 vs SQL 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236352/default-row-order-in-select-query-sql-server-2008-vs-sql-2012), rather each time it will choose the most optimized way. Therefore on the page 1 query using `TOP` it chose one way to order and on page 2 with `row_number()` it chose a different way to order. Thereby returning duplicate results in page 2 that were already in page 1. This was true even though I had many other order bys.

Mysql also seems not to have a default order by [SQL: What is the default Order By of queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746519/sql-what-is-the-default-order-by-of-queries).

I don't know if `Prisma` does the same thing with `mysql`. **Printing out the queries may shed light on if different queries are used for different pages**.

Either way if you're using pagination it may make sense, to do as you mentioned and to always use `id` as a final `order by`. Like this even if your other intended `order bys` allow the same record to be on multiple pages the final `order by` `id` will ensure that doesn't occur, since now you're forcing it to order by ids instead of choosing a more optimal approach that doesn't order by `ids`.

In your case since `user` `14` has `0` likes it can be on any page after `2`, `10` and `3` and still satisfy your `likesReceived` `orderBy`. But with the `id` order by then it'll always be on page 2, since page 1 will now have `4` and `6` as the last records, instead of `14`, due to the 2nd `orderBy` of `id`.

Comment: Very interesting! big thanks for this explanation, it's great :D

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the provided answer, just posting here what I replied on the Prisma repo issue directly:

What I suspect is happening here is that in the first case where you order only by the count, the count values are not unique (if I got your description correctly a lot of them have count 0). In this case I don't think the order within the values with the same count is stable between different requests at the database level. This is normal in the SQL world. The solution is to add a tiebreaker, a second field to order by that ideally is unique. This you did in the second request and then got a stable ordering.

So I'd say this is not a bug but expected behaviour from the database and therefore Prisma. The fix you already found, just add a second unique field to break ties or use that one as cursor directly.